# How to dial number starts with * in iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I am developing an iPhone app and I need it to call a number that starts with *, is there a way to overcome Apple's restrictions (I know they prevent that)?

Answer (score 1):

If Apple has explicitly restricted something then you can't just "overcome" it in the build in SDK. Usually the only way to get around Apple's security protocols is to develop an application strictly for Cydia.